# Proxying cockpit through Apache reverse proxy

Tags: cockpit

I'm trying to proxy cockpit[1] with Apache,

It opens the login interface, but when after login I get a blank screen, no errors, nothing. In devtools I found an ws error `Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 400`

The cockpit-ws daemon output this in its logs

```
cockpit-ws[14523]: received invalid or missing Upgrade header: (null)
cockpit-ws[14523]: Received invalid handshake request from the client
cockpit-ws[14523]: WebSocket from 192.168.123.2 for session closed
```

I'm running on Centos7 with cockpit 195

Here is the relevant configuration part

```
ProxyPreserveHost On                                     
ProxyRequests Off                                        

# allow for upgrading to websockets                      
RewriteEngine On                                         
RewriteCond %{HTTP:UPGRADE} ^WebSocket$ [NC]             
RewriteCond %{HTTP:CONNECTION} ^Upgrade$ [NC]            
RewriteRule .* ws://192.168.123.2:9090/%{REQUEST_URI} [P]

# Proxy to your local cockpit instance                   
ProxyPass / http://192.168.123.2:9090/                   
ProxyPassReverse / http://192.168.123.2:9090/
```

Yeah I'm not using virtual host I know, I'm trying to get this working at `/cockpit` url, but this another question

Here is `/etc/cockpit/cockpit.conf`

```
[WebService]                                                                                         
Origins = https://192.168.123.2:9090 wss://192.168.123.2:9090 http://192.168.123.2 ws://192.168.123.2
ProtocolHeader = X-Forwarded-Proto                                                                   
AllowUnencrypted = true
```

[1] https://cockpit-project.org/

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue,  I forgot to enable proxy_wstunnel module.

```
sudo a2enmod proxy proxy_wstunnel proxy_http ssl rewrite
```

whole Apache proxy setup is described here
https://github.com/cockpit-project/cockpit/wiki/Proxying-Cockpit-over-Apache-with-LetsEncrypt